# FasterXML schema generation for Maps and Object references

Tags: jackson, fasterxml

I have an issue generating a JSON Schema file with FasterXML.
The file output just shows

- `object` type for a `Map<String, String>`
- `null` type for `OtherBean`

> {
>       "type": "object",
>       "properties": {
>           "beanId": {
>               "type": "integer"
>           },
>           "beanName": {
>               "type": "string"
>           },
>           "beanMap": {
>               "type": "object"
>           },
>           "otherBean": null
>       } }

My Schema generation class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsonschema.JsonSchema;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

        JsonSchema jsonSchema = MAPPER.generateJsonSchema(MyBean.class);

        MAPPER.writeValue(new File("MyBeanSchema.json"), jsonSchema);

    }
}
```

MyBeans:

```
import java.util.Map;

public class MyBean {

    private Integer beanId;
    private String beanName;
    private Map<String, String> beanMap;
    private OtherBean otherBean;

    public MyBean() {
    }

    public Integer getBeanId() {
        return beanId;
    }

    public void setBeanId(Integer beanId) {
        this.beanId = beanId;
    }

    public String getBeanName() {
        return beanName;
    }

    public void setBeanName(String beanName) {
        this.beanName = beanName;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getBeanMap() {
        return beanMap;
    }

    public void setBeanMap(Map<String, String> beanMap) {
        this.beanMap = beanMap;
    }

    public OtherBean getOtherBean() {
        return otherBean;
    }

    public void setOtherBean(OtherBean otherBean) {
        this.otherBean = otherBean;
    }
}
```

OtherBean:

```
public class OtherBean {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly answering your question, but Schema Generation is moving to a separate module:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema/

which will have better functionality, and can evolve faster than old in-built generation.
So if possible, try using that. And then you can file bugs against this, for problems with generation.